# Custom Sorting in Mongoose

Tags: function, mongoose, mongoose-schema, custom-sort

I have the following schema of story:

```
story : {
  content: string,
  seenBy: Types.ObjectId[]
}
```

here `seenBy` is the array of users,

Now I have a list of stories and I want to sort the list based on the unseen story first and seen at last for a particular logged-in user,

means if the logged-in `userid` is 2 then story which has the particular `userid` in seenBy should come last and the other should come ahead.

I am not getting an idea of how to do it.

In the API I have logged in `userid`,

I have tried the following but it gives compile time error:

```
 const totalStories = await this.Story.find({})
      .populate(this.populateStory())
      .sort({ seenBy: (val) => {
          return val.includes(userid) ? -1 : 1
       }, updatedAt: 'desc' });
```

I searched many places but I did not get anything related to my problem statement.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I have come up with a solution,

Using the aggregate function a field can be added to the document temporarily and we can sort on that field as below:

```
const totalStories = await this.Story.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      seen: { $in: [authUser.id, '$seenBy'] },
    },
  },
]).sort({ seen: 'asc', updatedAt: 'desc' });
```

By this we can sort with any custom logic as the field `seen` will be boolean based on the data in the documents.

I got the idea from the below link: [MongoDB ($addField)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

Props:

1. You can write your custom logic (condition) and sort accordingly.
2. As it is a query so will give optimistic complexity rather than a sort() function on an array.

Cons:

1. Can't able to populate() because of aggregate (Note: As an alternate, you can use $lookup (work as a join) to populate data [MongoDB ($lookup)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)